# Grey square notification Torturous

Tags: android

I created an app which generates a notification, but the icon I set for that notification is not being displayed. Instead I get a white square.

[image]

From stackoverflow and other websites i try to look for solution but no luck.
Note: I am php developer and know limited andoroid development.

My code:
**AndroidManifest**

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_name" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
        <!-- [END fcm_default_icon] -->
        <!-- [START fcm_default_channel] -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/app_name"/>
```

Images are generated using image asset tools as shown below.

**NOTE** : It works well on my old samsung s7 edge but doesnot not work on my motog4 motog5 oneplusone and oneplusthree

Comment: Your notification icon should be like this: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar

Answer (score 0):

You notification icon has incorrect transparent areas. You must ensure, that your transparency is 100%, other alpha channel values will be mapped to white.

Comment: can you please give me an sample such image please

Comment: In Android Studio, right click on your resource folder, then create a new image asset. Select notification icon from the drop down, then select an image either from the pre-existing icons or from file and generate it. This should work. If you select one of the existing icons, they should work definitively.

Comment: Have you tried to run your app in the simulator? It should look the same there. Samsung supports notification icons with alpha channel. The Moto series does not. Can you post your icon somewhere to check whats going on there?